# Configure git branch in prompt

Tags: linux, git, bash

I have updated my bash file so that the current Git branch is displayed followed the instructions [here](http://code-worrier.com/blog/git-branch-in-bash-prompt/). What I ended up using is

```
PS1="\u@\h \W \$(__git_ps1)\$ "
```

However...

1. I can't see to be able to replace the `(branch)` to `[branch]`, i.e. show the branch name within brackets instead of parentheses.
2. The original version had colours:

   ```
   PS1="\[$GREEN\]\t\[$RED\]-\[$BLUE\]\u\[$YELLOW\]\[$YELLOW\]\w\[\033[m\]\[$MAGENTA\]\$(__git_ps1)\[$WHITE\]\$ "
   ```

   but when I used this I did not see any colours. How could I see colours and what would be a standard setting for the shell to use?

Comment: About 1), try `PS1="\u@\h \W \$(__git_ps1 "[%s]")\$ "` instead.

Comment: You've tagged your question with both the `linux` tag and the `git-bash` tag. Are you using Git on Windows or Linux?

Comment: @Jubobs:Linux. Is that tag for windows?

Comment: Git Bash is the bash shell that ships with the Windows version of Git.

Comment: Regarding 2), could you edit your question to add your colored version of the prompt? If the colors worked in the original definition, there must be something wrong in yours.

Comment: @Jubobs:Actually there is no coloring in my prompt.The PS1 I copied from the link tutorial has color definitions and I can not understand why they are not displayed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1 - Delimit the branch name with brackets instead of parens

Here is a relevant passage of the `.git-prompt.sh` file (which, in modern Git versions, contains the definition of the `__git_ps1` function):

```
#    3a) Change your PS1 to call __git_ps1 as
#        command-substitution:
#        Bash: PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
#        ZSH:  setopt PROMPT_SUBST ; PS1='[%n@%m %c$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
#        the optional argument will be used as format string.
```

`__git_ps1` accepts an optional argument that you can use to customize the format of the string. In your case, you should use

```
PS1="\u@\h \W \$(__git_ps1 '[%s]')\$ "
```

### 2 - Using colors

You can use colors as in the code in your question, but you need to make sure that the variables in question are defined. Put the following lines somewhere in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
RED=$(tput setaf 1)
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
BLUE=$(tput setaf 4)
MAGENTA=$(tput setaf 5)
WHITE=$(tput setaf 7)
RESET=$(tput setaf 0)
```

After sourcing your `~/.bashrc` file, you'll be able to use those colors.
For instance, here is a simplified version of your prompt with the current branch name (and surrounding brackets) highlighted in red:

```
PS1="\W \[$RED\$(__git_ps1 '[%s]')\]\[$RESET\$\] "
```

[image]

Comment: The colors still don't work.Unless I needed to do something in the part where you mention: `After sourcing your .bashrc file`.

Comment: Yes; sourcing the `.bashrc` file is a necessary step. Try to close your terminal/console, open it again (`.bashrc` will be sourced then) and then redefefine the prompt.

Comment: We have some progress. Using your PS1 for test everything (the prompt and the commands I input) are in gray now

Comment: @Jim Ok. `cd` to a Git repository, now. The current branch should appear in red.

Comment: I did. Everything is gray.

Comment: I just copied this to test the colors:`PS1="\W \[$RED\$(__git_ps1 '[%s]')\]\[$RESET\$\] "` and all is gray

Comment: And you've definitely defined `RED` in your `~/.bashrc` file, right? Also, what color is the background of your terminal?

Comment: Yes.I pasted the color definition just after this line. Does this matter? My terminal is white. But I can see colors in general (e.g. git grep etc)

Comment: You need to define `RED` and `RESET` *before* the new prompt definition.

Comment: See my edit; assuming you use black text on white background, that should be fine for you.

Comment: Yes!Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1. The `__git_ps1` function you're using takes a format string as an argument.  So you can pass in whatever you want with `%s` where you want the branch name to show up.  For example:

   ```
   PS1="\u@\h \W \$(__git_ps1 '[%s]')\$
   ```

No clue about the colors, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function parse_git_dirty {
    [[ $(git status 2> /dev/null | tail -n1) != "nothing to commit, working directory clean" ]] && echo "*"
}
function parse_git_branch {
    git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e "s/* \(.*\)/[\1$(parse_git_dirty)]/"
}
PS1="\[$Blue\][\[$Cyan\]\d\[$Blue\]] "          # Display date
PS1=$PS1"\[$Yellow\]\@:"                        # Display time
PS1=$PS1"\[$BGreen\]\w"                         # Display a green pwd
PS1=$PS1"\[$BCyan\]"'$(parse_git_branch)'       # Display a cyan git-branch
PS1=$PS1"\[$Color_Off\]$ "                      # Turn off color and end prompt
export PS1=$PS1
```

it produces something like this:

```
[Thu Sep 18] 12:44 PM:~/repos/test[master*]$
```